# What causes SQL syntax error 1064 in this code?

Tags: mysql, go

I'm trying to insert data into my new table, and I got sql error 1064.

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
`id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`update` INT(11),
`name` VARCHAR(255),
`dob` INT(11),
`status` INT,
`avatar` VARCHAR(255),
`province` VARCHAR(255),
`city` VARCHAR(255),
`district` VARCHAR(255),
`village` VARCHAR(255),
CONSTRAINT `pk_users` PRIMARY KEY (id))
```

```sql
INSERT INTO `users` (`update`, `name`, `dob`, `status`,`avatar`,
`province`, `city`, `district`, `village`) VALUES (1557227442, Cortez Mante, 702086400, 1, http://lorempixel.com/150/150/, Provinsi, Kota, Kecamatan, Kelurahan)
```

And I got error:

```sh
$ panic: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Mante, 702086400, 1, http://lorempixel.com/150/150/, Provinsi, Kota, Kecamatan, ' at line 1
```

I don't know exactly what cause the error. can anyone help me with this ?

btw, I am using Golang for crating and inserting to this table.

this is how I connect to mysql and create the table through Go:

```golang
func connect() (db *sql.DB) {
  dbDriver := "mysql"
  dbUser := "root"
  dbPass := "password"
  dbName := "user"
  db, err := sql.Open(dbDriver, dbUser+":"+dbPass+"@/"+dbName)

  if err != nil {
      panic(err.Error())
  }

  return db
}

func create_table() {
  db := connect()
  sql := fmt.Sprintf(
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
    "`id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT",
    "`update` INT(11)",
    "`name` VARCHAR(255)",
    "`dob` INT(11)",
    "`status` INT",
    "`avatar` VARCHAR(255)",
    "`province` VARCHAR(255)",
    "`city` VARCHAR(255)",
    "`district` VARCHAR(255)",
    "`village` VARCHAR(255)",
    "CONSTRAINT `pk_users` PRIMARY KEY (id)")

  fmt.Println(sql)

  insert, err := db.Query(sql)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
  }

  defer insert.Close()
}
```

this is how I insert the data:

```golang
func AddUser(u user.User) {
  db := connect()

  insert_users := "INSERT INTO `users` (`update`, `name`, `dob`, `status`, `avatar`, `province`, `city`, `district`, `village`)"
  values_users := fmt.Sprintf(
    "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
    strconv.Itoa(u.Update), u.Name, strconv.Itoa(u.Dob), strconv.Itoa(u.Status), u.Avatar, u.Province, u.City, u.District, u.Village)

  sql := insert_users + " " + values_users

  fmt.Println(sql)

  insert, err := db.Query(sql)

  if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
  } else {
    fmt.Println("success add user:", u.Id)
  }

  defer insert.Close()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

miisng quote around string values

```
 INSERT INTO `users` (`update`, `name`, `dob`, `status`,`avatar`,
        `province`, `city`, `district`, `village`) 
VALUES (1557227442, 'Cortez Mante', 702086400, 1, 'http://lorempixel.com/150/150/', 'Provinsi', 'Kota', 'Kecamatan', 'Kelurahan')
```

your contents  string

```
 'Cortez Mante' 

 'http://lorempixel.com/150/150/'

'Provinsi', 'Kota', 'Kecamatan', 'Kelurahan'
```

and you should close each single statements  with semicolon

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
`id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`update` INT(11),
`name` VARCHAR(255),
`dob` INT(11),
`status` INT,
`avatar` VARCHAR(255),
`province` VARCHAR(255),
`city` VARCHAR(255),
`district` VARCHAR(255),
`village` VARCHAR(255),
CONSTRAINT `pk_users` PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
;

 INSERT INTO `users` (`update`, `name`, `dob`, `status`,`avatar`,
        `province`, `city`, `district`, `village`) 
VALUES (1557227442, 'Cortez Mante', 702086400, 1, 'http://lorempixel.com/150/150/', 'Provinsi', 'Kota',
     'Kecamatan', 'Kelurahan')
;
```

Comment: :) I know you are chasing your 100K but this one has a well used Dup

Answer (score 1):

Add var char values in the single code this will work

`province`, `city`, `district`, `village`) VALUES (1557227442, 'Cortez Mante', 702086400, 1, 'http://lorempixel.com/150/150/', 'Provinsi', 'Kota', 'Kecamatan', 'Kelurahan');